# Payum, figure out value for $paymentClass in prepare.php

Tags: payum

I am trying to get payum to work with paypal_pro_checkout, but I am stuck in the prepare.php file:

```js
<?php
//config.php


include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Payum\Core\PayumBuilder;
use Payum\Core\Payum;

$paymentClass = Payment::class;


/** @var Payum $payum */
$payum = (new PayumBuilder())
  ->addDefaultStorages()
  ->addGateway('gatewayName', [
    'factory' => 'paypal_pro_checkout',
    'username' => 'REPLACE IT',
    'password' => 'REPLACE IT',
    'partner' => 'REPLACE IT',
    'vendor' => 'REPLACE IT',
    'tender' => 'REPLACE IT',
        'sandbox' => true
    ])

    ->getPayum()
;

    <?php
// prepare.php

include __DIR__.'/config.php';

$gatewayName = 'paypal_pro_checkout';

/** @var \Payum\Core\Payum $payum */
$storage = $payum->getStorage($paymentClass);

$payment = $storage->create();
$payment->setNumber(uniqid());
$payment->setCurrencyCode('EUR');
$payment->setTotalAmount(123); // 1.23 EUR
$payment->setDescription('A description');
$payment->setClientId('anId');
$payment->setClientEmail('foo@example.com');

$payment->setDetails(array(
  // put here any fields in a gateway format.
  // for example if you use Paypal ExpressCheckout you can define a description of the first item:
  // 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => 'A desc',
));


$storage->update($payment);

$captureToken = $payum->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken($gatewayName, $payment, 'done.php');

header("Location: ".$captureToken->getTargetUrl());


?>
```

This is according to [the docu of Payum](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/paypal/pro-checkout/get-it-started.md) but with $paymentClass I run into trouble. They did not define it in the Paypal config.php, but not defining it throws an error. When I take the definition from the getting started example (as above in config, I get

Fatal error: Uncaught Payum\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A storage for model Payment was not registered. There are storages for next models: Payum\Core\Model\Payment, Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject, Payum\Core\Model\Payout. in C:\Users\User\Desktop\www\payum_test\vendor\payum\core\Payum\Core\Registry\AbstractRegistry.php

I am using this without any framework and I am not familiar with theses Models mentioned in the error

Answer (score 0):

I understand `$paymentClass` contains the payment model class. If you use standard Payum models then it can be `Payum\Core\Model\Payment`. Otherwise - your own model class - `MyApp\Model\Payment`